# Sails connect-redis adapter

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js

I want to use redis commands for `ZSET` elements. In sails, I enabled the `connect-redis` adapter as per the docs. Now how do I access the redis commands with this redis client which is already created(I guess) when sails is lifted?
Also do I need to create a global variable for it?

```
/* config/session.js */

adapter: 'connect-redis',
host: 'localhost',
port: 6379,  
db: 0,
// pass: <redis auth password>,
prefix: 'sess:',
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be available as `sails.config.session.store.client`, and if you have globals enabled, it would work in any place in your code.